# Como copiar un archivo de texto lineas impares y otro archivo lineas pares y volcarlo en otro

Tags: java

y así con todas las lineas una por una linea de tal modo que quede

```
archivo1linea1 (nueva linea)
archivo2linea1 (nueva linea)
archivo1linea2 (nueva linea)
archivo2linea2 (nueva linea)
```

**Código**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      String line = "";
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("origen.txt"))) {

        try (BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("origen1.txt"))) {

            try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("destino.txt", true));) {

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)  {
                    bw.write(line);
                    bw.newLine();
                    br.readLine();
                   line=br1.readLine();
                   bw.write(line);
                   bw.newLine();
                   br1.readLine();


                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cual es tu duda? a mi me parece que ya casi lo tienes, excepto que me parece que el ultimo br1.readLine() esta de más. Ademas, vas a tener problemas si alguno tiene más lineas que el otro.

Comment: Hola User, has duplicado las preguntas. Por favor , borra está o la [anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108448/como-puedo-copiar-las-lineas-impares-de-un-txt-y-copiarlo-en-destino-y-las-pares). Intenta mejorar la explicacion siguiendo [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Es esto lo que obtengo con ese codigo menos con la ultima linea de codigo br1.readLine() 1
x
3
x
5
x
7 con origen 1 y origen  x
2
x
4
x
6
x
8  1
x
3
x
5
x
7 q son respectivamente. Destino: 1
x
3
2
5
x
7
4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para trabajar más fácilmente con las líneas pares e impares, te propongo volcar el contenido de los archivos a sendos `ArrayList<String>` y trabajar con ellos.

### Volcar el contenido de `BufferedWriter` a `ArrayList<String>`

Esto puede hacerse de varias maneras. A partir de `Java-8`, es casi trivial:

```
// Java 8
try (BufferedReader brPar = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("origen.txt"))) {
    List<String> pares = brPar.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Con `Java-7`, es un poco más complicado:

```
// Java 7
try (BufferedReader brImpar = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("origen2.txt")))
{
    String line;
    impares = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((line = brImpar.readLine()) != null) {
        impares.add(line);
    }
}
```

A lo mejor lo puedes separar en otro método así:

```
private List<String> volcarALista(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException
{
    String line;
    List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        lista.add(line);
    }
    return lista;
}

// Java 7
try (BufferedReader brImpar = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("origen2.txt")))
{
    impares = volcarALista(brImpar);
}
```

### Trabajar con tus `ArrayList<String>`

Cuando los has llenado, trabajar con tus listas requiere un simple bucle `for`:

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("destino.txt"))) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pares.size(); i++) {
        bw.write(impares.get(i));
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(pares.get(i));
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
```

Aunque piensa que **si tus archivos no tienen el mismo número de líneas, esto podría dar lugar a errores**. Lo podrías resolver comprobando qué lista es más grande.